# Problems with importing a document and changing the strings of the document and outputting the new strings in a new .txt document

Tags: java, string

It should then output a new .txt document, but when it does, it outputs the original document. I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type String
```

If I comment out the return "ok", but otherwise it creates a new document with the same details as the original document.

What could be the cause?

```
public static String Replace(String filename) {
    try {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        System.out.println(file);
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String s = "";
        while(file.hasNextLine()){

            s = file.nextLine();


            if (s.equals("X")) {
                s = "0";
                b.append(s).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            } else {
                b.append(s).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

        }
        try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("test1,1.txt"))) {
            out.print(b);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
    }
    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, it works as expected. What is your source file ?

Comment: I dont know how to attach a document to a message here so bear with me!

The input looks like this:

X X 8 1 X X 5 X X
9 6 X X 8 X X X X
X 5 X X 3 6 X 9 8
X X 7 X 6 9 X 1 2
X X 6 8 X 7 3 X X
8 1 X 4 5 X 6 X X
4 2 X 6 7 X X 8 X
X X X X 4 X X 6 3
X X 5 X X 8 7 X X

Comment: Your "equals" condition will only work if the whole read line is "X" , is this what you want ?

Comment: Try a debugger and step through the line `if (s.equals("X"))` to see if what you expect is the case or not.

Comment: Also, if you remove `return "ok"`, the error is quite clear in what it says.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! This did the trick. I simply deleted the if-statement and replaced it with a

          s = s.replaceAll("X", "0");

The program now works as I intended!